# Jquery ajax upload progress event behavior

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to show progress bar when upload files with ajax.
To do this I used XMLHttpRequest in this way.

```
$.ajax ({
    url: test.php, <-- upload files and return true
    data: formData,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    type: "POST",
    success: function (data) {
        if (data) console.log("OK");
    },
    xhr: function() {
        var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
        var percentComplete = 0;
        console.log(percentComplete);
        xhr.upload.addEventListener( "progress", function ( evt ) {
        if ( evt.lengthComputable ) {
                percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
                percentComplete = parseInt(percentComplete * 100);
                console.log(percentComplete);
            }
        }, false );
        return xhr;
    }
});
```

Unfortunately I noticed that the result of the success comes after a few seconds
the xhr percentComplete equals to 100.

```
CONSOLE LOGS

0
24 (or other number between 1 and 99)
100
..and than after a few second
OK
```

I wish the percentComplete equals to 100 when the ajax call ends with success.

How could I do? Thank you